# jQuery animated div on scroll

Tags: jquery, css

I have this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if($("#1").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop());
    $("#1").animate({"color":"#efbe5c","font-size":"52pt", "top":"0", "position":"fixed"}, 1000);
}, function() {
$("#1").animate({"color":"#333","font-size":"52pt", "top":"0", "position":"fixed"}, 1000);
  });
});
```

in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GELTP/1294/) As you can see, when you start to scroll, the text animates (I did get this from Stackoverflow, but lost the link, so thanks to the people who contributed to the first post) What I would like is for the text to animate back to its original state when the content once again reaches the top.

Any help is always much appreciated

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of browser support do you need? The catch with animating back is you need to know the original style.

Once method I can think of is using the window.getComputedStyle method to retrieve the styles for the element and store them in an object array to use for the animate back. You will need a couple extra supporting functions.

I tested the following code in Chrome, IE 9, and FireFox 24 and it seemed to work pretty well. It all depends on what styles you work with. Since you are animating, however, this should work with most.

Also, I stored your styles and speed in variables to make it cleaner. Fiddle below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var aniCss = {"color":"#efbe5c","font-size":"52pt", "top":"0", "position":"fixed"};
    var speed = 1000;
    var props = getProps(aniCss);
    var curCss = getStyles($("#1"), props);
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >0) {
            $("#1").animate(aniCss,speed);
        }
        else {
            $("#1").stop(true,true).animate(curCss,speed);
        }
    });

    function getProps(css) {
        var props = [];
        for (k in css) {
            props.push(k);
        }
        return props;
    }
    function getStyles($ele, props) {
        var compCss = getComputedStyle($ele[0]);
        var styles = {};
        for (var i = 0;i<props.length;i++) {
            var name = props[i];
            var prop = compCss.getPropertyValue(name);
            if (prop != '') { styles[name]=prop;}
        }
        return styles;
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ajqQL/1/

**Update:** Just saw that in jQuery 1.9 they added the ability to pass an array of properties to retrieve the values. You can simplify the above by just using jQuery .css() method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var aniCss = {"color":"#efbe5c","font-size":"52pt", "top":"0", "position":"fixed"};
    var speed = 400;
    var props = getProps(aniCss);
    var curCss = $('#1').css(props);
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >0) {
            $("#1").animate(aniCss,speed);
        }
        else {
            $("#1").stop(true,true).animate(curCss,speed);
        }
    });

    function getProps(css) {
        var props = [];
        for (k in css) {
            props.push(k);
        }
        return props;
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NZq8D/1/

Comment: Daved it worked really well,Chrome and IE have a delay and need a screen refresh on the text, however, I'm planning on using a solid background colour. Works perfect with that